# How do I set an associated record in a Spring controller, if the post request contains a foreign ID?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm building a CRUD app in Spring, and so far I have 2 entities: `Employee`, and `Department`. I have a REST controller, and I can't seem to figure out how to set the department (or even just get the `departmentId` from the JSON request that was sent to the REST controller). Here's my controller method:

```
    @PostMapping
    Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee newEmployee, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        // I thought if departmentId was in the request, it would automatically set the department
        // but it doesn't. Setting a breakpoint and inspecting `newEmployee` shows that department is null.
        // What's the standard way of setting the associated record, if the POST request contains the foreign ID?
        return employeeRepository.save(newEmployee);
    }
```

Department:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Department {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;

    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what my problem was.

```
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private Department department;
```

I had added `@NotNull` to these relationship definitions, which is incorrect. The `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` annotations take `optional` as a  parameter, in order to specify whether these associations are null or not.